# TypeError show_poll() got an unexpected keyword argument 's'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to redirect the user after submitting a form to the polls list. The form is saved in the admin after submitting but the redirection is failing anyone can help me with this?

My views.py:

```
def show_poll(request, id):

  p = Poll.objects.get(id=id)
  pops = p.option_set.all()
  context = {
    'poll': p,
    'options': pops,
  }
  return render(request, "show_poll.html", context)

def create_poll(request):

  c_form = PollForm(request.POST or None)
  data = {}
  data["create_form"] = c_form
  if c_form.is_valid():
    poll = c_form.save(commit=False)
    poll.slug = slugify(poll.title)
    poll.save()
    return redirect("show_poll", s=poll.slug)
  return render(request, "create_poll.html", context=data)
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('show/poll/<int:id>/', views.show_poll, name="show_polls"),
    path('c_poll/<slug:s>/',views.show_poll, name="show_poll"),
    path('create/poll/',views.create_poll)
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two paths that refer to the *same* view, indeed:

```
path('show/poll/<int:id>/', views.show_poll, name='show_polls'),
path('c_poll/<slug:s>/',views.show_poll, name='show_poll'),
```

This thus means that the `show_poll` can be called by the first or second pattern. In case of the first one, it will call this with `id`, and without an `s`.

If the second pattern "fires", then it will cal `show_poll` with `s=…` with `…` the slug.

You can perhaps combine the two and work with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def show_poll(request, id=None, s=None):
    qs = Poll.objects.all()
    if id is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(pk=id)
    if s is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(slug=s)
    p = get_object_or_404(qs)
    pops = p.option_set.all()
    context = {
        'poll': p,
        'options': pops,
    }
    return render(request, "show_poll.html", context)
```

another option is to make two separate views, one for the first pattern and one for the other pattern.